# Not able to map local db with (volumes in mysql image) in Docker-Compose file

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Docker-Compose File

```
 db:
   image: mysql:latest
   environment:
     MYSQL_DATABASE: 'tel'
     restart: 'always'
     MYSQL_USER: 'root'
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test'
   ports:
    - '3306:3306'
   volumes:
      - my-db:/usr/local/var/mysql

 app:
   image: "myapp/app:v1"
   ports:
     - "9292:9292"
   environment:
     SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db/data 
     SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
     SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: 'test'

   depends_on:
     - db

volumes:
 my-db:
```

Error while Doing docker compose

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'data.token' doesn't exist
>    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]
>   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar!/:8.0.13]

**the table "data" is present locally but not able to map it from docker compose**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error was due to database version mismatch , in local and docker container both were having different versions of mysql
so after applying database migration and adding proper data it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think your jdbc url is incorrect. It should be:

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:mysql://db/tel"
```

The format of the string is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html).

Btw, I think the `restart: 'always'` should be outside the `environment` block.

Comment: the datasourse url was correct and all the config i have mentioned above was correct problem was in database version mismatch , Thanks